# Start and Stop JS HTML animation with JS

Tags: javascript, html, animation, button, shapes

So we pretty much have this program working fine, we just need a little help, or a good pointer in the right direction on how we would start and stop the animation.  I have tried several methods and none seem to have worked.  I have spent a good amount of time online attempting to find help for the solution.  I have come to believe that the problem lies somewhere in the lines that tell the shape to move. Thank you for any help in advance.

JS:

```
var myGamePiece;

function startGame() {
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
    myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
    },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;    
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY;        
    }    
}

function updateGameArea() {
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGamePiece.newPos();    
    myGamePiece.update();
}

function moveup() {
    myGamePiece.speedY -= 1; 
}

function movedown() {
    myGamePiece.speedY += 1; 
}

function moveleft() {
    myGamePiece.speedX -= 1; 
}

function moveright() {
    myGamePiece.speedX += 1; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="HallettBrocatoLab2.js"></script>

<style>
canvas {
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="startGame()">

<div style="text-align:center;width:480px;">
  <button onclick="moveup()">UP</button><br><br>
  <button onclick="moveleft()">LEFT</button>
  <button onclick="moveright()">RIGHT</button><br><br>
  <button onclick="movedown()">DOWN</button><br><br>
  <button onclick="start()">Start</button>
  <button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
</div>

<p>If you click a button the red square will start moving. Click the same button many times, and it will move faster and faster.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but you're trying to clear the Interval? isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

The clearInterval() method clears a timer set with the setInterval() method.
The ID value returned by setInterval() is used as the parameter for the clearInterval() method.

add a function end `pauseGame()`

```
function pauseGame(){
    clearInterval(this.interval);
}
```

change the definition of `updateGameArea` function

```
function updateGameArea() {
    if(condition_to_stop){
        myGameArea.pauseGame();
    }
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGamePiece.newPos();    
    myGamePiece.update();
}
```